# Is there a way from where I can keep watch on other mobile screen?

Tags: security, screen

I really would like to know if I can keep a check on other android mobile devices.
Scenario is I have Android application Developers team with me and gave them phones and tablets for testing and development.I want to keep track of their work and would like to see their screens anytime I want.

If anyone have answer to it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article showing some options if you have a PC:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/mirroring_an_android_device_screen_onto_your_desktop

In my limited experience, realtime viewing is tricky.  If screen snapshots are OK, I'd recommend Teamviewer as I've always found their products robust:

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/mobile-device-support.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).